# loading image not display using jquery mobile

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

I wanted to show loading image before json data load, I have made individual pages for my JQM project & called below function on page load. I am having trouble showing loading image as per below

JS code

```
function getEmployeedata() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var session_token = localStorage.getItem("session_token");
    var Employeedata = {
        'session_token': session_token,
            'search_text': ''
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: 'abc.com/EmployeeListController',
        data: Employeedata,
        dataType: 'Json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#employeeList li').remove();
            $.each(data.emplist, function (index, employee) {

                $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="employeeDetail.html?id=' + employee.emp_no + '" style="padding:2px">' +
                    '<div class="imgGender ' + employee.gender + '"></div>' +
                    '<h4>' + employee.emp_name + '</h4>' +
                    '<p>' + employee.designation_desc + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="ui-li-count ui-body-inherit ' + employee.emp_status + '">' + employee.emp_status + '</span></a></li>');
            });
            $('#employeeList').listview('refresh');
            $("#findEmployeePage").show();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
        timeout: 60000,
        error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
            alert("no connection");
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
    });
}
```

here is some HTML code for your info

```
<body onLoad="getEmployeedata()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
  <div data-role="page" id="findEmployeePage" style="display:none;">
```

I am going to achieve show loading image before json data load and then show above div. Currently my all code working fine but loading image not works..
hope you guys understand my question... please help on the above issue

Comment: run `getEmployeedata()` on `pagecontainershow` not onload of body.

Comment: @Omar Thank you for your reply... but no luck

Comment: delay hiding the spinner to see it working `setTimeout(function () { $.mobile.loading("hide"); }, 5000);`